# Running node.js & puppeteer as a spawned process on windows gives error puppeteer.launch is not a function

Tags: c#, node.js, windows, puppeteer

I have a c# program that runs node.js as a separate process using puppeteer to convert html text to pdf.

If the script is in the same directory as the node_modules  directory containing puppeteer then all works fine.

If I define the node_path environment variable to reference the node_modules directory and the script is located elsewhere then node.js returns the error "puppeteer.launch is not a function"

The same node command works fine in a batch file.

Comment: Im sure is related to path relative. When you include puppeteer require('puppeteer') try to put the full path e.g. "C:/docs/node_modules/puppeteer"

Comment: I wish to avoid any dependency between the script and the location of the puppeteer modules. Besides the definition of the node_path environment variable is sufficient (in the case of a batch file) and is at least partly sufficient when node is run as a spawned process as the error is quite different if the node_path variable is not defined